# How to optimize Adobe AEM code and prevent access and adaptation of node on each request?

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

We have a problem with the performance of our publisher. I've profiled the JVM and found a hotspot in the code related to our custom linktransformer. The most CPU is being used in locating, reading and adapting a JCR node that contains configuration values for the site.

This makes sense since the linktransformer is calling this code for every link it encounters. So I am looking for a way to "cache" the locating, reading and adapting the node part. However I am not sure how to do this, and how to do so in a manner that in case the value of the node changes the change is picked up.

I could imagine making a singleton OSGI service that does this. However then I am not sure how to make sure it reloads if the node changes.

Could someone give some hints on how to tackle this from a conceptual level? I am not looking for the code but more for a route to take?

Help would be much appreciated.

(aem 6.1)

Answer (score 0):

you could implement OSGI service and bind the configuration using `sling:osgiConfig` bound to the service pid of the Service Class. Refer to sample [here](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/10/how-to-work-with-configurations-in-cq.html) Also refer to AEM documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/configuring-osgi.html)

In addition to this you could use `ManagedService` to ensure properties are updated automatically on change.
Refer to sling documentation [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-config-admin.html)

Sample code -

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
@Service({YourServiceInterface.class, ManagedService.class})
public class YourService implements YourServiceInterface, ManagedService {

/**
     * Activate.
     *
     * @param componentContext the component context
     * @throws org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException the configuration exception
     */
    @Activate
    public void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) throws ConfigurationException {
        updated(componentContext.getProperties());
    }

/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService#updated(java.util.Dictionary)
     */
    @Override
    public void updated(Dictionary<String, ?> configuration) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (configuration != null && !configuration.isEmpty()) {
            // Handle your logic for config items population here
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here.

1. Create an OSGi service that contains the config itself (don't keep it in the JCR)
2. Create an EventHandler that would listen on EVENT_TOPIC's related to resource changes on your specific jcr-path - this EventHandler could then invalidate your cache'ing Model whether it's an OSGi service or a pure old static.